# AdMob RewardedVideoAd.loadAd always returns "failed to load ads, error code: 0"

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I'm using firebase-ads:9.2.0 with API level 24.

And unity-ads aar module is imported by adding compile(name:'unity-ads', ext:'aar') to my build.gradle.

Everything goes fine if I choose to use UnityAds API directly.

But when I try to integrate unity-ads with AdMob like this:

```
    mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance( this );

    mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(new RewardedVideoAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
            logger.debug("onRewardedVideoAdLoaded");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
            logger.debug("onRewardedVideoAdOpened");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
            logger.debug("onRewardedVideoStarted");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
            logger.debug("onRewardedVideoAdClosed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
            logger.debug("onRewarded");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
            logger.debug("onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
            Toast.makeText( 
                getApplicationContext(), 
                "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
    });

    AdRequest adRewardRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("E921B48960E16DA3ABD13C4AFB7052A4")
        .build();

    mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd( 
        getResources().getString(R.string.reward_ad_unit_id), 
        adRewardRequest );
```

It always returns

> There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
>   Failed to load ad: 0.

Is there anything I did it in the wrong way?

Or I just missed some steps?

Here is my AdMob page screenshot:

[image: AdMob page]

Answer (score 6):

Okay, I found solutions.

The first thing is that I didn't include adapters in my project.

I have to download the adpaters here:
[Third-party network adapters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/mediation-networks)

And put it into the libs folder.
These adapters are not included in the SDKs(if you download it from github).

Second, I have to remove this line out of my code.

```
.addTestDevice("E921B48960E16DA3ABD13C4AFB7052A4")
```

It seems like if the AdMob treat this device as a test device, there will be no any video ad to be downloaded(at least in my case).

Same thing happens if I choose to use the AVD, they force to show test ads on these emulators.

So I change to Genymotion, remove the addTestDevice() and then it works.

Comment: so, how to test the Admob Rewards ads without .`addTestDevice` ? thanks

Comment: You have to use Genymotion or your phone. You can find a test mode feature on your ad network settings page. http://i.imgur.com/D1mLbYk.png

Comment: Where to add this "addTestDevice" ? Also, what is the parameter? Does it need to change somehow for each use case?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Your answer will be found in AdMob documentation and the console logs. If there's no any thing like this, then this answer might be out of time.

Comment: @KimiChiu What I've found is for the fake ones, but not for test devices: for init, it's `MobileAds.initialize(context,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"` . For rewarded, it's `RewardedAd(context,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917")` and for interstitialAd, it's `interstitialAd!!.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"`

Comment: @androiddeveloper You're talking the test ad unit, not test device. You'll found how to use `addTestDevice` in the code snippet of my question and the parameter from your console logs after the AdMob is initialized.

Comment: @KimiChiu I see. But what is the difference? I can set that if it's in debug mode, use the test-ad-unit, and if not, use the real ones... Is the test-device used for when I want to use it on release?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Because in the old days, we don't have any test ad unit. You can still use this on your physical device. In case you accidentally click the ads.

Comment: @KimiChiu I see. Thank you. Do you suggest using it instead of just what I wrote? Do you use test-device?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Yes and no. If you accidentally click the ads, Google may stop pushing you ads and suspend your account. So use test ad unit while you integrating ad networks. After then, use your ad unit id and `addTestDevice`.

Comment: @KimiChiu I see. I think I should add it, then. But, does it do anything even on release version of the app?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Yes, but only on the device you added.

Comment: @KimiChiu OK thank you. And I've found that in order to find what is the string I need to use, I filter by "ads" in logcat, as written about here: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#add_your_test_device

Answer (score 2):

> Usually this happens for newly created ads, so wait for an hour and
>   try again.

public static final int ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR

Something happened internally; for instance, an invalid response was received from the ad server.

**Constant Value: 0**

Source: [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR)

Comment: I am using the test ad units provided by Admob but still it fails to load.

Comment: I am still waiting for a long time and there is nothing change

Comment: Create a new ad in admob and try

Answer (score 1):

I'm using interstitial ads, but I believe it is the same problem. Google sometimes gives code that doesn't work, don't ask me why is that.

Add this after your `mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd()` method:

```
mRewardedVideoAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            //your code when Ad is loaded
            //you can show your ad immediately, but I don't suggest it
            if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                mRewardedVideoAd.show(); //this shows ad immediately
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
        }
    });
```

Or you can set the AdListener, don't show it immediately, but rather make a new method:

```
public static void displayAd() {
    if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        mRewardedVideoAd.show();
    }
}
```

And this way, you can call this method from any activity, which shows the ad almost instantly (because it was already loaded), without the need to loading it again.

Comment: I've already added a listener and it called onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad() after i called mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd().
So the mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded() is always false.

Comment: The issue is somewhere else then. As I said, I didn't use rewarded video ad, so I thought it might be similar. Check google's code line by line and see if you missed any line.

Comment: Just one more question, did you initialize mobile ads? in my app I need to write MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "<ad_unit_id>"); before everything else. Did you do this as well in your app? If not, try adding that. You can find ad unit id on your AdMob account.

Comment: I have MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), ADMOB_APP_ID); in onCreate. And they only use codes just like the code snippet I posted.